# How to make the planehelper rotate at a point that is not the origin

Tags: three.js

I have set a clip plane in the scene that is not at the origin. I want the clip plane to rotate around its axis at its current position. I found that the existing planehelper class could not do this. What is the method? If I need to implement a new class myself, what good ideas are there? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the planeHelper in a new [`Group()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Group).
2. Change the position of planeHelper in the opposite direction of the new pivot point you want. If you want it to pivot around `(1, 0, 2)`, move it to `(-1, 0, -2)`
3. Add the group to the scene.
4. Rotate the parent group.